# Split-path with Long directory name in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm confused as to how to use the Split-Path properly for Powershell version 5 when I have a very long directory structure as I am using a Dropbox drive on my PC within Win 10.

My problem domain is to recursively travel several directories of software changes I had made, there are several versions and sometimes each directory have two or three sub directories each deep at several places.

The directory structure I have and it begins at C:\Users\XXXX\Dropbox\Doing\SoftwareName\Releases

The "Release" field is to show the release number I wanted to be able to summarise my report as to the version number which is under the ..\Release directory. Location is the last (sub)-directory hence using -Leaf and the filename as File.

> The code I used (EDIT: Shown with changes I learnt. I'm happy with Curly braces in the output due to referencing a collection.

```
 cd C:\Users\XXXX\Dropbox\Doing\SoftwareName\Releases

   Get-ChildItem -Path (Get-Location) -Filter *.cs -Recurse | 
ForEach-Object {
    $Release = $_.Directory.Split('\') -like "*Version*"
    $Location = Split-Path ($_.DirectoryName) -Leaf
    $File = $_.Name
        ForEach-Object {
            New-Object PSObject -Property @{
                Release = $Release.ToString()
                Location= $Location.ToString()
                File = $File.ToString()
                }
        } | Format-Table -AutoSize  Release, Location, File
}
```

> Output (the first three lines to simplify)

```
 Release                                                              
   Location   File                                  
        C:\Users\XXXX\Dropbox\Doing\SoftwareName\Releases\Version1\StoryWriter StoryWriter Chapter1.cs
        C:\Users\XXXX\Dropbox\Doing\SoftwareName\Releases\Version2\StoryWriter\Outline\BeachScene BeachScene Chapter2.cs
        C:\Users\XXXX\Dropbox\Doing\SoftwareName\Releases\Version3\StoryWriter\Outline\Conversations Conversations Chapter3.cs
```

> Outcome I'm after is

```
Release    Location File            
-------    -------- ----                                              
Version1 StoryWriter Chapter1.cs
Version2 BeachScene Chapter2.cs
Version3 Conversations Chapter3.cs
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you can acheive this using calculated properties of select-object but to continue what you are doing:

i got rid of the 2nd `foreach-object` that you had inside the first because it was serving no purpose. also if you are going to use `foreach-object` you need to pipe a collection as input.

Since you want to get the version folder name showing up under the `release` column i used regular expressions to parse the path. maybe there are better way to do that but anyways serves the purpose.This will work as long as the version folder is preceeded by the `releases` folder.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path (Get-Location) -Filter *.cs -Recurse | 
ForEach-Object {

        New-Object PSObject -Property @{
                    Release = ([regex]::Matches($_.DirectoryName,'(?<=Releases\\)\w+\\' ) | select -ExpandProperty value) -replace '\\'
                    Location= Split-Path ($_.DirectoryName) -Leaf
                    File = $_.Name
                }


} | Format-Table -AutoSize  Release, Location, File
```

Comment: Thank you @Esperento57 and Kiran for your feedback. I took few days break to look at this with fresh eyes and while taking aboard regex and split I worked out a solution.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "c:\temp" -Filter *.cs -Recurse -file | where FullName -like '*\Release\version*\*\*' | %{
    $Array=$_.FullName -split '\\'
    $RankRealease=$Array.IndexOf("Release")
    [pscustomobject]@{Release = $Array[$RankRealease+1];Location= $Array[$RankRealease+2];File = $_.Name}
}
```